# Why does console build generate radically different project.assets.json than that generated with VS IDE build?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, devenv

We have a big solution with ~100 projects which depend on many NuGet packages, some of which are internally developed. This question is about the main web application which is the center of this solution.

We would like to consider migrating to the new SDK style projects (where we can) and the first step was to migrate ALL the projects to PackageReference. And here came a major bummer - when the code is built

- on the console with `msbuild`, we get `System.Buffers` version 4.0.3.0 in the bin folder.
- on the console with `devenv /build`, we get `System.Buffers` version 4.0.3.0 in the bin folder.
- in the VS IDE (I use 16.7.7), we get `System.Buffers` version 4.0.2.0 (**!!!**) in the bin folder.

I have identified that the difference is driven by the difference in project.assets.json generated for the web application in question.

The difference is massive, but absolute majority of differences is that package.assets.json for the console build contains much more content that for the IDE build. And then there is the System.Buffers:

[image]

Notes:

- No project explicitly references System.Buffers
- We have a process in place that ensures that all the projects reference exactly the same version of the particular NuGet package. Failure to comply fails the PR build. However, it does not help with transitive dependencies of these NuGet packages. So, we are forced to deal with assembly binding redirects (even if all of our projects are unsigned - does not matter, many dependencies are signed)
- No code has changed between the builds, only the bin folder of the respective Web Application was deleted

My question - has anyone faced it? I am completely taken aback by the fact that `devenv /build` produces exactly the same **project.assets.json** file as `msbuild`.

My theory - it has to do with Fast Up To Date Heuristic employed by VS. But I do not want to disable it - it is a huge time saver. Just a theory, a weak one, because no code has changed, after all.

My methodology was to run the following script:

```
$FileItem = Get-Item .\bin\_PublishedWebsites\MyWebApp\bin\System.Buffers.dll

del $FileItem.Directory.FullName -r -Force
r.ps1 -NoPull -Main -NoValidateSolutions
[reflection.assemblyname]::GetAssemblyName($FileItem.FullName)
Copy-Item .\UI\MyWORKBits\obj\project.assets.json c:\temp\_msbuild.project.assets.json

del $FileItem.Directory.FullName -r -Force
devenv Main.sln /build
[reflection.assemblyname]::GetAssemblyName($FileItem.FullName)
Copy-Item .\UI\MyWORKBits\obj\project.assets.json c:\temp\_devenv.project.assets.json

del $FileItem.Directory.FullName -r -Force
$VSInstanceFinder = (Get-ToolFromNuGet VSInstanceFinder 1.0.20009.1).FullName
Add-Type -Path $VSInstanceFinder
$dte = [VSInstanceFinder2.Program]::Find((Get-Item .\Main.sln).FullName)
$dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build()
while (!(Test-Path $FileItem.FullName))
{
    Write-Host -NoNewline '.'
    Start-Sleep 10
}
[reflection.assemblyname]::GetAssemblyName($FileItem.FullName)
Copy-Item .\UI\MyWORKBits\obj\project.assets.json c:\temp\_ide.project.assets.json
bc c:\temp\_console.project.assets.json c:\temp\_devenv.project.assets.json
bc c:\temp\_console.project.assets.json c:\temp\_ide.project.assets.json
```

**Minimal Reproduction**

I am still working on a minimal reproduction that would show off the issue in its entirety. However, in order to demonstrate that project.assets.json is different, albeit in an innocent way, enough is a tiny project.

**Common.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{04455D86-A7A4-41E5-B3ED-B0BC65EAFDFD}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>xyz.Common</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>Bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>Bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Dummy.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr">
      <Version>3.5.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**dummy.cs**

```
using Antlr;
```

Let us build it in VS IDE and check the project.assets.json file:

```
C:\work\vsbug [master]> dir .\obj\project.assets.json | sls projectName

obj\project.assets.json:76:      "projectName": "Common",


C:\work\vsbug [master]>
```

So the projectName is reported as **Common**. Now let us build on the console:

```
C:\work\vsbug [master]> msbuild /restore .\Common.csproj /v:q
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\work\vsbug [master]> dir .\obj\project.assets.json | sls projectName

obj\project.assets.json:76:      "projectName": "xyz.Common",


C:\work\vsbug [master]>
```

This time the projectName is **xyz.Common**.

As far as I am concerned this is a benign difference. But it should not be there in the first place and could be a symptom of the issue we are experiencing with our big solution.

Note that using SDK style project eliminates the difference, but I cannot use it in our big solution.

The `devenv /safemode` does not seem to restore any NuGet packages at all, so the code fails to compile and I could not figure out how to make it work. Completely useless currently.

I will try to produce a minimal repro with different package set, but I already have a question - why project name is different?

**EDIT 1**

There is a proposition to run `msbuild.exe -t:restore` from a pre build step. Since my solution has 127 C# projects (plus one utility project), modifying each and every one is not reasonable. Instead, I added the following target to `Directory.Build.targets`:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="MSBuildRestore" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == True">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe&quot; /t:Restore /v:q /nologo /m $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I still have to evaluate the impact of this change on the build. After all, this command recurses down to every project on which this one depends. And each and every project is going to call it.

Luckily it seems NOT to break the Fast Up To Date heuristic of Visual Studio, so I will run with it a bit to see if it has no unexpected surprises.

**EDIT 2**

Unfortunately, generating the project.assets.json from a prebuild step is not a solution. Apparently, this file serves as an input to the build. The following simple scenario shows the behavior:

1. Build in msbuild
2. Set `DisableFastUpToDateCheck = true` to disable the Fast Up-To-Date heuristic
3. Open VS
4. Build in VS with binary logging (use the Project System Tools to generate the logs)

Inspecting the logs reveal that projects are actually recompiled, because the `project.assets.json` files are regenerated before the each build.

Not good.

Comment: What happens if you'll use `dotnet` CLI?

Comment: I cannot. The code uses legacy project style. Not SDK style projects.

Comment: First, you should make sure that you have specify the same configuration and platform for the build process under `VS IDE`,`devenv /build`, `msbuild`. Also, if your VS IDE has installed other third party extensions or tools, it will interface the build process of the project. `devenv /build` and `msbuild` will not reload the third party packages. And you should check if it is the main problem. Maybe you could use [devev /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start VS to test it.

Comment: A sample we could investigate would be immensely helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @zivkan - I am working on it.

Comment: I also face the same issue on a default net framework console project with `PackageReference`. I will test the issue on more projects and find any possible tips.

Answer (score 0):

**Research**

It seems to be an issue between **VS IDE restore** and **msbuild restore** and I also faced this issue in many projects and PCS. So it is quite an issue so far and thanks for pointing out this problem.

================================

`projects.assert.json` on VS IDE restore:

[image]

================================

`projects.assert.json` on msbuild restore:

[image]

I have reported [this issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1242086/why-projectassertjson-file-is-different-between-vs.html) and you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe the issue in detail so that it will get more **Microsoft's** attention. And I hope the Team will give you a satisfactory reply.

**Suggestion**

**Since** the process may take a while, **as a suggestion** to eliminate the difference, you could try this function:

you only have to add a command line on the pre-build event of your project in **VS IDE**:

**1)** right-click on your project **Properties**-->**Build Events**-->write this on the **pre-build event command line**:

```
msbuild $(MSBuildProjectFullPath) -t:restore
```

**2)** And then delete `bin` and `obj` folder, rebuild your project in **VS IDE**.

The **premise** is that you should copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` into **System Environment Variable** `PATH`.

If my suggestion does not satisfy you, you can just ignore it.

Comment: The problem runs deeper, because the differences I observe in our big solution are vaster. Not just names, but missing libraries in VS IDE produced project.assets.json. This is hard to reproduce with a small sample and I do not have much time to play with it. As for your suggestion - are we to delete bin and object before **each and every** build?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Maybe this is just a simplified representation of this different behavior. And it is quite strange since I also faced this in my side. Hope the team will help us resolve the issue. Besides, when you use my command, you do not have to worry about -----`are we to delete bin and object before each and every build?`.

Comment: Because no matter you are building the project in `VS IDE` or `MSBuild`,`msbuild restore` will be executed every time without skipping, `project.assert.json` and other restored files will always be generated by msbuild, always be overwritten by msbuild restore. So you do not have to delete `bin` and `obj` folder.

Comment: It will take me some time to evaluate your suggestion.

Comment: It is kind of you to do that:)

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**. I will accept your answer for now, even though it does not really answer the question - why it happens?

Comment: I am forced to demote it from the accepted answer. Turns out in VS, implementing this workaround causes complete rebuild of the code due to `Input file "C:\xyz\git\UI\Platform\obj\project.assets.json" is newer than output file "obj\Debug\xyz.Web.Platform.dll"`.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of posterity, I just came across this question in search of a similar error involving a missing `[Project].csproj.nuget.dgspec.json`. In my case, the CI pipeline was using an older version of NuGet than Visual Studio was invoking locally. I added a "NuGet tool installer" step to force the newer version and that solved the problem.